# find 1 and replace it with regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to duplicate a form and replace the value 1 with 2, 3 etc depending on the number of forms.

Here's my html:

```
<div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput">

  <input id="show_upload_image_link_1" type="text" size="36" name="kandibox_theme_hero_options[show_upload_image_link_1]" value="<?php echo $hero_options['show_upload_image_link_1']; ?>" /> 
 <input id="show_upload_image_link_button_1" class="button upload_images" type="button" value="Upload Image" />

  <div class="actions">
      <button class="clone">Clone</button> 
      <button class="remove">Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my query:

```
var regex = /^([0-9]+)$/;
var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length;

$("button.clone").live("click", function(){
  $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone()
    .appendTo("body")
    .attr("id", "clonedInput" +  cloneIndex)
    .find("*").each(function() {
        var id = this.id || "";
        var match = id.match(regex) || [];
        if (match.length == 3) {
            this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
  }
});
cloneIndex++;
});

$("button.remove").live("click", function(){
  $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
});
```

So far it adds extra forms but It will not replace the value 1 in name or value.

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tfFLt/590/

Comment: ... and? Please explain, if you get an error message (if so, which one) or if the results differ from your expectation (if so, how).

Comment: Does this address your questions?  http://jsfiddle.net/tfFLt/601/.  Looks like the name attribute is still wrong, but I think the fix is straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the final version with cleanup to avoid code repetition:

```
$("button.clone").live("click", function(){
    var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length + 1;
    var new_Input = $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone();
    updateClonedInput(cloneIndex, new_Input);    
});

$("button.remove").live("click", function(){
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();

    $(".clonedInput").each( function (cloneIndex, clonedElement) {
        updateClonedInput(cloneIndex + 1, clonedElement);
    })
});
```

For the `input` IDs calcultion and other properties I dropped the regex thing altogether. I also changed the way the new input is handled: first I create a `newInput` and then I process it. Easier and more readable approach.

When you delete one input the `input` fields will also be renumbered to 1, 2, 3...
The fiddle has been updated to reflect this.

PS. Watch out that if you delete the first input then you are left with no more input areas or button to add a new one... :-) Solution: either this button is removed from the input form or you put a condition to not allow removal if there is only one input left.

Hope it helps!

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vs8p5/)

Comment: Here you only update the Id of the HTML, but in his code he keeps using cloneIndex which never is updated then.

Comment: Yes. I noticed that. Working on it. But my code also has another issue. If you delete a section the next created one will maybe have repeated numbers.

Comment: There are two ways to fix that, if the numbers don't need to be in order (e.g. 1 2 3 4....) but can be ( 1 (remove 2) 3 5 6 7) Than you can just replace the cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length +1; in my answer to cloneIndex++. Otherwise you will have to update your .clonedInput on every clone operation. (Testing how many you have and then renumber them) In that case I would change my ID's to an array id=clonedInput[0] ,...

Comment: Ideally if 3 forms were created, i.e. 1, 2, 3 and number 2 was deleted, I would like number 3 to be changed to number 2?

Comment: With the final solution I proposed that doesn't happen. But you can easily do that by traversing all `.clonedInput`and changing them and their children when the `button.remove` is clicked. I will not have time to do this today but can take a look tomorrow. But then also the new form numbering must be changed to what I had proposed initially. This `cloneIndex++;` must change to this: `cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length + 1;`

Comment: This now seems to work perfect although if I change it to the latest query and change .live to .on it no longer works?

Comment: I'm happy it worked for you! But beware because .live() is deprecated and should not be used. Are you restricted to use a old version of jQuery? BTW, I have dropped the use of regular expressions because they tend to obfuscate the code and should be used to manipulate data/text and not DOM elements. If instead of 5 elements to be changed you had 100 then maybe a regex would have been useful. But in that case please leave a good comment of what you are doing to make sure colleagues (or even yourself) will understand what is going on when reviewing your code for improvements or bug fixes. ;-)